# ng-click error with angular 1.2.0 and 1.2.1

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have some angular code that worked in angularjs 1.2.0-rc.1, rc.2 and rc.3. But it doesn't work in 1.2.0 and 1.2.1.

I have illustrated the problem on http://plnkr.co/edit/KBYFJQ2sZeOJ79Hid1gG

My HTML is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.1" data-semver="1.2.1"
            src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="menuEntry in menuItems">
        <a ng-href="#" ng-click="{{menuEntry.action}}">{{menuEntry.text}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>

</html>
```

and my angular code is

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
        var menuItems = [
            {
                text: "Log off",
                action: 'logoff()'
            }
        ];

        var logoff = function () {
            alert("logoff called")
        };
        $scope.menuItems = menuItems;
        $scope.logoff = logoff;
    });
```

If I run this code with 1.2.0-rc.3 it runs without error and I get an alert box when I click on the link. But if I run it with 1.2.0 or 1.2.1 I get an error:

```
 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'menuEntry.action' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{menuEntry.action}}] starting at [menuEntry.action}}].
```

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for `ngClick` don't indicate that you can use {{..}} bindings for the callable expression. I think it may just work by accident in older versions, and an implementation change in the newer versions has broken it.

Really this seems a strange way to be hooking your code up anyway. Are you able to replace the action attribute with a real function to call? e.g.

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.logoff = function () {
            alert("logoff called")
        };

        $scope.menuItems = [
            {
                text: "Log off",
                action: $scope.logoff
            }
        ];
    });
```

Then

```
<a ng-href="#" ng-click="menuEntry.action()">{{menuEntry.text}}</a>
```

If you do need to start with a dynamic expression you can call it with `$scope.eval`. e.g.

```
var menuItems = [
    {
        text: "Log off",
        action: 'logoff()'
    }
];

angular.forEach(menuItems, function(menuItem) {
    menuItem.callableAction = function() { return $scope.$eval(menuItem.action); }
});
```

then

```
<a ng-href="#" ng-click="menuEntry.callableAction()">{{menuEntry.text}}</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem!!
Tested it on http://plnkr.co/edit/vIE6GKT4hDCWOx3wSvOp?p=preview
Actually the "logoff" function does not have to be placed in scope, but that is a small detail

Comment: Agreed. Wasn't sure where else you would be using it from so I kept it there for simplicity. Glad you got it working :)